# How can I make my buttons responsive on different mobile devies?

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design

I am trying to get into **React** and responsive design and wanted to create my first application using the **Grommet** library.

My only problem is that the buttons vary in size depending on the screen size. On the iPad pro for example they appear tiny and on smaller devices way too large:

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/grommet-row-responsive-buttons-dvv88?file=/src/index.js) is a link to **CodeSandbox**.

I think that I messed it up with the containers. I can not figure out how to make my buttons responsive so that they doesn´t vary in sizes too much on different devices.

Any help is appreaciated!

---

**UPDATE**

A custom **theme** with breakpoints already exists in the **App.js** :

```
import { themeFile} from "./themes/themeFile";

export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Grommet className="App" theme={themeFile}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Menubar />
            <Box direction="column" align="center">
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/summaryPage">
                  <PlayerView />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/topic">
                  <Topic />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                  <Home />
                </Route>
              </Switch>
            </Box>
          </Provider>
        </Grommet>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Breakpoints** are already set in in the **themeFile.js** as follows:

```
import { deepFreeze } from "grommet/utils";

export const themeFile= deepFreeze({
  name: "themeFile",
  rounding: 8,
  spacing: 28,
  defaultMode: "light",
  global: {
    breakpoints: {
      small: {
        value: 896,
        borderSize: {
          xsmall: "1px",
          small: "2px",
          medium: "4.666666666666667px",
          large: "7px",
          xlarge: "14px"
        },
        edgeSize: {
          none: "0px",
          hair: "1px",
          xxsmall: "2px",
          xsmall: "3.5px",
          small: "7px",
          medium: "14px",
          large: "28px",
          xlarge: "56px"
        },
        size: {
          xxsmall: "28px",
          xsmall: "56px",
          small: "112px",
          medium: "224px",
          large: "448px",
          xlarge: "896px",
          full: "100%"
        }
      }
)};
```

I updated the link to the **CodeSandbox** repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons are not the driver of the layout and their layout is controlled by the wrapper layout component, in your case, it is the Box component (line #11) on the codesanbox.
The Box component is automatically responsive to the custom breakpoints you have defined and that seems to work as expected.

Now, since the buttons are using the full real estate of the Box, one approach will be to refine the Box layout and put constraints into it.
For example, by adding the `width` prop to the Box, you can limit the max-width of the Layout container and that will impact the stretch of the Buttons, so a simple constraint of `width="250px"` or `width="medium"` should constrain the Box, and hence the buttons will have a more conservative layout as follows:

[image]

There are more ways to tackle this but a good rule of thumb is to let the layout component drive the layout.
One more thing, to limit the minimum & maximum sizes of the Button, you can always set `width={{ min: "medium", max: "medium" }}` on the Box component and that should do the trick without the involvement of ResponsiveContext, and control the Button sizes to be more consistent across small and wide screens.

If you do want to involve the `size` prop of ResponsiveContext, you can use the `size` within the `width` logic such as `width={size==="small" ? "150px" : "250px"}` and that should give you more precise width calculation across different screens, but it might be overkill if you can solve the problem with simply using the `width` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

if you plan to make the buttons responsive on different devices, you can use @media query. It is simple & you can define the resolution ranges for different devices.

You can find about @media query on the below link. Hope this answer would be helpful for you.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add wrap `prop` to `Box` component like:

```
<Box wrap width="medium" border={{ size: "medium" }} direction="row-responsive">
```